# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, appfuse

I am using Appfuse to develop my application. I got an exception as below.
I guess the hibernate mapping had a problem with special column name **ADSL_DEVICE.VALIDATE** (using notation) cause errors. Please help me to resolve this problem.

#### When execute the test case, i get the warn and error message

> Hibernate: select NODE_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual
>   Hibernate: insert into NODE (AREA_ID, DESCRIPTION, FIRMWARE_VERSION, IS_ENABLE, IS_VISIBLE, MIB_VERSION, NAME, PARENT_ID, NODE_TYPE_ID, SERIAL_NUMBER, SHORT_NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   
> Hibernate: insert into ADSL_DEVICE (ADSL_NAME, ADSL_SERIAL_NUMBER, CONNECTION_REQUEST, HARDWARE_VERSION, IP_ADDRESS, MANUFACTURER, OUI, PRODUCT_CLASS, PROVISIONING_CODE, SOFTWARE_VERSION, **VALIDATE**, NODE_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   
> WARN - SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(143) | SQL Error: 1747, SQLState: 42000
>   
> ERROR - SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(144) | **ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification**
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.289 sec <<< FAILURE!
>   testAddAdslFirmware(org.appfuse.dao.AdslDeviceDaoTest)  Time elapsed: 8.249 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

#### Then I define the column name by adding quotes: ADSL_DEVICE."VALIDATE"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = AdslDevice.TABLE_NAME, uniqueConstraints =
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = AdslDevice.SERIAL_NUMBER))
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = AdslDevice.NODE_ID)
public class AdslDevice
    extends Node
    implements java.io.Serializable {

// Constant
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ADSL_DEVICE";
public static final String NODE_ID = "NODE_ID";
public static final String ADSL_NAME = "ADSL_NAME";
public static final String SERIAL_NUMBER = "ADSL_SERIAL_NUMBER";
....

@Column(name = "\"VALIDATE\"", length = 1)
public String getValidate() {
    return this.validate;
}

public void setValidate(String validate) {
    this.validate = validate;
}

....
}
```

#### But i still get error, the Hibernate Query seem to be deadlock and do not response any messages when execute query. What the error is? How can i fix the bug?

> Hibernate: select NODE_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual
>   Hibernate: insert into NODE (AREA_ID, DESCRIPTION, FIRMWARE_VERSION, IS_ENABLE, IS_VISIBLE, MIB_VERSION, NAME, PARENT_ID, NODE_TYPE_ID, SERIAL_NUMBER, SHORT_NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   
> Hibernate: insert into ADSL_DEVICE (ADSL_NAME, ADSL_SERIAL_NUMBER, CONNECTION_REQUEST, HARDWARE_VERSION, IP_ADDRESS, MANUFACTURER, OUI, PRODUCT_CLASS, PROVISIONING_CODE, SOFTWARE_VERSION, "VALIDATE", NODE_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

#### This is my test case:

The AdslDeviceDao class extends GenericDao from Appfuse

```
public class AdslDeviceDaoTest extends BaseDaoTestCase {

@Autowired
private AdslDeviceDao adslDeviceDao;

@Test
public void testAddAdslFirmware() {
    NodeType type = new NodeType();
    type.setId(1L);

    AdslDevice node = new AdslDevice();

    // Node values
    node.setArea(new Area(1L, "Ha noi"));
    node.setDescription("Node desc");
    node.setFirmwareVersion("1.0");
    node.setIsEnable((short)1);
    node.setIsVisible((short)1);
    node.setMibVersion("v1");
    node.setName("Node name");
    node.setNodeType(type);
    node.setSerialNumber("4578787864896");
    node.setShortName("S1");

    // adsl values
    node.setAdslName("Adsl name");
    node.setAdslSerialNumber("4578787864896");
    node.setHardwareVersion("1.0");
    node.setIpAddress("10.2.4.58");
    node.setManufacturer("Vnpttech");
    node.setOui("6.1.2.3");
    node.setProductClass("Product class");
    node.setProvisioningCode("6630");
    node.setSoftwareVersion("11");
    node.setValidate("1");
    Node nodenew = adslDeviceDao.save(node);

    flush();
    assertEquals("F23", nodenew.getName());
    assertNotNull(nodenew.getId());
 }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Oracle, it looks like [VALIDATE is a keyword](http://psoug.org/definition/VALIDATE.htm). Try renaming the column.

Comment: yes. i have to rename the colunm then the program already run
thank you, Matt